# Strange error when parsing string to date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, windows-phone

When I try to parse date like this:

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact("August 11, 2013, 11:00:00 PM", "MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It works correctly but when I do thing like this :

```
string s ="‎August ‎11, ‎2013, ‏‎11:00:00 PM";
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get this error :

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your string

```
string s = "‎August ‎11, ‎2013, ‏‎11:00:00 PM";
```

Includes [0x200e(8206) character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) at the beginning and end of `August`. You can see it easily by

```
var chars = s.ToCharArray();
```

Seems to be a copy+paste problem

*You can remove those chars by:*

```
var newstr = new string(s.Where(c => c <128).ToArray())
```

Comment: so how can i remove it as i already get it from sting in model?

Comment: @AhmedEmad `var newstr = new string(s1.Where(c => c <128).ToArray())`

Comment: @AhmedEmad The reason why the left-to-right and right-to-left marks are there is probably that the string comes from some Arabic text with English month name and left-to-right ordered digit groups in it. You can remove the non-ASCII chars like in the answer, but if they are always there in the same place, why not just parse them, as in `DateTime.ParseExact(s, "\u200EMMMM \u200Edd, \u200Eyyyy, \u200F\u200Ehh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Answer (score 3):

Haha, I found it.

First of all, there is nothing wrong with both of your code. Both works fine. **Just your strings are not equal.** There are some hidden characters on your second one.

Your first `"August 11, 2013, 11:00:00 PM".Length` is 28

but second `"‎August ‎11, ‎2013, ‏‎11:00:00 PM".Length` is 33

Let's try this code;

```
string s = "August 11, 2013, 11:00:00 PM";
string s1 = "‎August ‎11, ‎2013, ‏‎11:00:00 PM";

char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
char[] c1 = s1.ToCharArray();

foreach (var ch in c)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch);
}

foreach (var ch1 in c1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch1);
}
```

Output will be;

```
A
u
g
u
s
t

1
1
,

2
0
1
3
,

1
1
:
0
0
:
0
0

P
M
? // <-- What the hell?
A
u
g
u
s
t

? // <-- What the hell?
1
1
,

? // <-- What the hell?
2
0
1
3
,

? // <-- What the hell?
? // <-- What the hell?
1
1
:
0
0
:
0
0

P
M
```

As a solution, don't copy paste any string to your code :).

Comment: You realize you misspelled `length` every time, right? :)

Comment: @SmartDev Ups, 7 years old mistake, fixed (:

Answer (score 2):

Your second string has hidden characters.

Run this:

```
string s1 = "August 11, 2013, 11:00:00 PM";
string s2 = "‎August ‎11, ‎2013, ‏‎11:00:00 PM";

Console.WriteLine(s1.Length); // 28
Console.WriteLine(s2.Length); // 33
```

Specifically, as char arrays, the second one is this:

```
s2.ToCharArray();
{char[33]}
[0]: 8206 '‎' // ????
[1]: 65 'A'
[2]: 117 'u'
[3]: 103 'g'
[4]: 117 'u'
[5]: 115 's'
[6]: 116 't'
[7]: 32 ' '
[8]: 8206 '‎' // ????
[9]: 49 '1'
[10]: 49 '1'
[11]: 44 ','
[12]: 32 ' '
[13]: 8206 '‎' // ????
[14]: 50 '2'
[15]: 48 '0'
[16]: 49 '1'
[17]: 51 '3'
[18]: 44 ','
[19]: 32 ' '
[20]: 8207 '‏' // ????
[21]: 8206 '‎' // ????
[22]: 49 '1'
[23]: 49 '1'
[24]: 58 ':'
[25]: 48 '0'
[26]: 48 '0'
[27]: 58 ':'
[28]: 48 '0'
[29]: 48 '0'
[30]: 32 ' '
[31]: 80 'P'
[32]: 77 'M'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was hit with this too. In my case, a UI automation test failed because IE seems to add this LRM (Left-to-right) mark automatically (Firefox and Chrome do not). A quick line of code that strips it away:

```
Regex.Replace(date, @"\u200e", string.Empty)
```