# Error while converting String to DateTime. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#, string, datetime

```
String test = "‎22/11/2009";
```

i tried following steps but no luck

```
1)DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)

2)DateTime.ParseExact(test, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But Its still giving the error

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I tried the following

```
String test = "‎22/11/2009";
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
```

Still getting same error
Please help me to get it resolved.

Comment: Does the first give the same error? And the second one is definitely going to fail!

Answer (score 4):

Your `test` string contains a secret character which it's [ascii value](http://www.asciitable.com/) is `63`. But actually, it is [Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (U+200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) character which equals `"\u200E"`. It is `200E` in [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and `E2 80 8E` in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Take a look;

[image]

And it's bytes represented as `byte[] {226, 128, 142}`

[image]

Looks like you copied this value from somewhere else. It works fine if you write your string manually.

```
string s = "22/11/2009";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 22.11.2009 00:00:00
}
```

Comment: `test.Length` is 11 where as it should be 10.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Yep, this is happening because of a secret character in it.

Comment: Moreover when you use arrrow key, between " to 2 it takes 2 keypress instead of one.

Comment: I think this is a Left to Right order mark of an UTF8 string - have a look at my solution further down. And maybe the user cannot just rewrite the string but needs to handle an existing string from another source.

Comment: @Marwie Right. This character seems it's ascii value as `63` which is a question mark(`?`) in `ToCharArray()` method. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a [Left to Right Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) at the start of your string - 3 bytes which are invisible by looking at the string in the debugger.

> The left-to-right mark (LRM) is a control character or invisible formatting character, used in the computerized typesetting of text that contains mixed left-to-right scripts (such as English and Russian) and right-to-left scripts (such as Arabic, Persian and Hebrew). It is used to set the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction.

The 3 bytes are `0xe2 0x80 0x8e` and they are causing the error.

```
String test = "‎22/11/2009";
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test));
```

have a look at hex - if you can get rid of those bytes the parse will work. You can remove the 3 bytes by doing this:

```
var test2 = new string(test.Where(c => c <128).ToArray())
```

And then do the parse:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(test2, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is in fact a doublette of [Strange error when parsing string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298208/strange-error-when-parsing-string-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Will server your purpose.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRrFys)**

Comment: I tried it  String test = "‎22/11/2009";
            DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US")); Still Getting error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRrFys
check the Fiddle Demo

Comment: Thanks its works but my format is MM/dd/YYYY its my mistake to mentioned as dd/MM/YYYY. Is there any other way to handle the (MM/dd/YYYY) formate ?

Comment: Downvoters any reason?????

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the culture format in the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "en-us" for example. With the current Cultureinfo you are using, this string isn't valid.

e.g.

> System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;            
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
string test = "22/11/2009";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/MM/yyyy",provider,style);
```